# Flutter: How many blocs to do? Looking for an architectural advice. I am new to BloC and planning to write an app

Tags: flutter, bloc

I need an advice concerning an architectural solution. My app has 5 screens that use information from the same JSON file.

- (1) List of companies,
- (2) List of companies on the Google Map,
- (3) Detailed information about a company,
- (4) Search of a company by name,
- (5) Comparison of prices provided by each company.

The prices change every minute and can be fetched by a user.

Additionally, I have other screens, that do not depend from this first JSON data:

- (6) favorites,
- (7) about project, and
- (8) one page that shows information from other JSON file.

Also, I keep in mind global variables for whole app such as:

- language,
- type of device.

**What would you recommend:**

1) Make 4 separate blocs for:

- language and type device
- 5 screens that depend from the first JSON
- Favorites
- One screen that depends from other JSON

2) Make separate bloc for each screen

3) Any other more suitable solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a separate bloc for each screen, but only if that screen has a logic. If a screen simply displays some info, like yours `(3) Detailed information about a company`, then bloc isn't required.

> language,
>
> type of device.

These aren't global variables, and can be accessed from `BuildContext`. For example, you can get the current platform by accessing `Theme.of(context).platform`